# disprove: $A$, $B$, $C$ are pairwise disjoint subsets of $V$; $A\cup B$, $A\cup C$ are bases of $V$; then $Sp(B)=Sp(C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Prove or disprove:
>   If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint subsets of vector space $V$, such that $A\cup B$ and $A\cup C$ are bases of $V$, then $Span(B)=Span(C)$.

I consider an example:
I take $A=\{(1,0)\}$, $B=\{(0,1)\}$ and $C=\{(1,1)\}$ as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

I know that this one example is enough to disprove the statement. However, I want to know how to go about with proving/disproving this claim, if I were to do it using no specific examples.
Would proof by contradiction where, we take
$(1)$ $A$ and $B$ such that $\{A,B\}$ is linearly independent, and
$(2)$ $C$, every element of which can be expressed as a linear combination of $A$ and $B$ (satisfying other conditions)
be enough/correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case you can not do a general proof of contradiction as there exist choices of $A,B,C$ and $V$ where the statement is true.
So at some point you would need to make some assumptions as for example if $B,C$ contain exactly one element that those are not multiples of each other.

In total, I can not think of a way to disprove this statement generally as it holds in some cases.
But as you mentioned, your solution is perfectly fine.